# yocto do_install() cp overwrite?

Tags: linux, yocto, recipe

I want to implement my yocto project recipe bb file like this:

```
do_install() {

  install -d  ${D}/usr/www/ ${D}/etc 
  cp -R  ${S}/code ${D}/usr/www/xxx
  **if statment**
  cp -Rf  ${S}/customer/code ${D}/usr/www/xxx
  install -m 0644 ${S}/config/lighttpd.conf ${D}/etc/lighttpd_hitron.conf
```

}

if some statment is true, it will using cp to overwrite the usr/www/xxx 's code folder,
but it seem not working, the usr/www/xxx 's content still the same,

and if do this it will work :

```
do_install() {

  install -d  ${D}/usr/www/ ${D}/etc     
  cp -R  ${S}/customer/code ${D}/usr/www/xxx
  install -m 0644 ${S}/config/lighttpd.conf ${D}/etc/lighttpd_hitron.conf
```

}

so i assume that its cp's overwrite fail?
or some other reasons?

thanks all a lot！

Comment: As long as you don't show the code, the questions cannot possibly be answered

Comment: hey thanks for reply, my code is just there,
just want to know why cp can't overwrite the folder.

Comment: What's your if condition?

Comment: if condition is not the point~
just to determine the environment variable exists or not
and I test it's can work.

Comment: Thats exactly why we kept asking for the actual code: its likely your environment variable isn't set when do_install runs

Comment: I'am sure that's not problem because I test a lot and know the if statement is not the point. delete the first two line it can work, delete if statement it can't work, so I focus on using cp to overwrite on .bb file. I write down the if statement just point out the logic.